# Search users Amazon Cognito with ListUsers API or iOS SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am creating an iOS application in Swift and I cannot find a way to search or get a list of Cognito Users with API. Per Amazon Documentation, it says to use the ListUsers API; however, it does not provide an endpoint to make the request and it is rather difficult to authenticate REST API requests with AWS so is there anyway to do this via iOS SDK? These are the parameters I would like to include in my Request.

```
[
        "AttributesToGet": ["username" ],
        "Filter": "username ^= \"micheal\"",
        "Limit": 10,
        "UserPoolId": "\(AWSCognitoUserPoolId)"
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to search through the Mobile SDK.

For iOS

```
 // Make a AWSCognitoListUsers Request
    let getUsersRequest = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest()

    // Add the Parameters
    //getUsersRequest?.attributesToGet = ["username"]
    getUsersRequest?.userPoolId = AWSCognitoUserPoolId

    // Make the Request
    AWSCognitoIdentityProvider(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolId).listUsers(getUsersRequest!, completionHandler: { (response, error) in


        // The response variable contains the Cognito Response

    })
```

Comment: Hello! I am having a similar issue now. What pod (and then import) do you need in order to use AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest()?
This is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416551/aws-cognito-getting-user-information-from-the-sub/56416800#56416800

Answer (score 1):

There is a a restful API endpoint to do it, because using the aws CLI you can do it. [Command Line List User Pool](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/aws-cognito-scripts/blob/master/aws_list_user_pool.rb)

the aws CLI is a good way to check out if the interface can do it.

How to do it in the IOS SDK is another matter.  There is little relationship (none) between the restful command set and the SDK method names. I think it is something you ask the CognitoIdentityProvider to do... I think it is listUsers or thereabouts, and I think you can list the pools as well.

+1 the other answer to this

Answer (score 0):

**Here is working code to fetch user lists fro Cognito.**

```
//IAM User Key and Secret Key Required
let IAMUserKey = “****”
let IAMSecretKey = “****”

//Set Credentials
let credentialsProvider : AWSStaticCredentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: IAMUserKey, secretKey: IAMSecretKey)
let serviceConfiguration: AWSServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
        
//Register Identity Provider
AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.register(with: serviceConfiguration, forKey:UserPoolID)
        
//Request
let getUsersRequest = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest()
getUsersRequest?.userPoolId = UserPoolID
//mentioned name of attributes in array - name, given_name, username, email and so on
getUsersRequest?.attributesToGet = ["name"]
//Add Value in filter you want to search 
getUsersRequest?.filter = "name = \”jen\””
//It will search string in including string
//getUsersRequest?.filter = "name ^= \"jen\""
   
AWSCognitoIdentityProvider(forKey: UserPoolID).listUsers(getUsersRequest!,completionHandler: {(response, error) in
  print("response:\(String(describing: response))")
  print("error:\(String(describing: error))")
})
```