# AWS Cognito - get user by phone number

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to implement a function that will return the email of a given user, and I'm wondering if there's a way to get find a Cognito user by their phone number?

Comment: You can do it via the ListUsers API, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364720/search-users-amazon-cognito-with-listusers-api-or-ios-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ListUsers` API

**Request Syntax:**

```
{
    "AttributesToGet": [email],
    "Filter": "phone_number ^= \"+1123-456-7890\"",
    "Limit": 1,
    "UserPoolId": "us-west-2_samplepool"
}
```

In the **iOS SDK**, you can use the [AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/a50e487cc71fc9345bdd55b8bdfe0eb08c7250ac/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/CognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderModel.h#L3980) request class.

```
let getUsersRequest = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest()

getUsersRequest?.attributesToGet = ["email"]
getUsersRequest?.userPoolId = "MyAWSCognitoUserPoolId"
getUsersRequest?.filter = "phone_number ^= \"+1123-456-7890\""

AWSCognitoIdentityProvider(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolId).listUsers(getUsersRequest!, completionHandler: { (response, error) in

})
```

You can look at one of our [tests](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/a50e487cc71fc9345bdd55b8bdfe0eb08c7250ac/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderUnitTests/AWSGeneralCognitoIdentityProviderTests.m#L3553) for example.

Comment: Hello! I am having a similar issue now. What pod (and then import) do you need in order to use AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest()?
This is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416551/aws-cognito-getting-user-information-from-the-sub/56416800#56416800

Comment: `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider`