# AWS Cognito / Getting user information from the sub

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I have a working iOS app using AWS Cognito AWSMobileClient where users can sign in and log in/out with AWSAuthUI.

What I want to do next is: having a sub from another user (e.g. 7y873ff7-.....u9h4k) I would like to get the information from that other user.

After searching the net it seems that I need to use something called ListUsers, but I am not 100% confident. Can anyone confirm this and give me some tip about how I need to go to get done what I want? Knowing that I am working in Swift.

...... Later updating of the post .......

Following examples I have found on the net; here is some code I have put together as a trial to start with.

```
let getUsersRequest = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest()

getUsersRequest?.attributesToGet = ["email"]
getUsersRequest?.userPoolId = "MY-POOL-ID"
getUsersRequest?.filter = "sub = \"SOME-USER-SUB\""

AWSCognitoIdentityProvider(forKey: "MY-POOL-ID").listUsers(getUsersRequest!,completionHandler: {
    (response, error) in
    print("OK, Here we are!")
})
```

But I never see the message: *OK, Here we are!*

So I must be doing something wrong. Of course MY-POOL-ID and SOME-USER-SUB are real data that I take from my AWS console.

Comment: What error do you get? Is the user authorized to call ListUsers? Do you have an identity pool set up with a proper role?

Comment: Reading my post you can see that I don't even reach the point where there is a chance to print an error (otherwise the message would be printed ... and I would have checked for a possible error). For you 2nd question .... it becomes interesting: this may be where I start to mess up. What do I need to have the user be authorized to call ListUsers? What is the proper role you are referring to?

Comment: It's an API, you should get some kind of answer. At least an HTTP code, 200, 401, 403, something. Anyway, updated my answer.

Comment: OK, well; then what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [ListUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) API, indeed.

[Here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest.html) is its documentation for AWS iOS SDK. One of the filters you can apply is for "sub".

The user calling `ListUsers` must have a role assigned that will grant it access to that API. Have a look at [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/) for an example in JS.

However, **you can't allow everyone to list all users in the pool**, that would be a huge security hole. Permissions to list all users should be reserved to application administrators, and only if needed. Instead, what you can do is set up a Lambda function on AWS, called through API Gateway. The function would take the sdb as input and would return the email address. The role attached to that function would give it access to call `ListUsers` for your pool. That would limit the amount of information your users can get about others, but your Lambda should still run checks to make sure it's not abused. For example, if user X wants to get the email address of user Y, user Y should approve that in advance.

I don't know your use case, but in general, allowing anyone to get information about any user of your app should be done with care. Any interaction between users should be transparent to them and agreed to. Keep in mind that users can log in to Cognito from outside your application if they can find the app ID and secret token. When giving a user access to anything, think about how it can be misused. You might realize that you should rethink how you approach the problem.

Comment: OK, thanks. The first link you mention I had already found, not the second. But both are not very helpful in the sense they don't give examples on how to use the API. For example if I start by instantiating an object of type AWSCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersRequest (in order to try something) the first message I get is an "unresolved identifier", meaning I am not using the right import (or pod)  at some point. Those documents have a lot of unwritten assumptions and are very good for people who "already know", not so much for the rest of us.

Comment: Assuming that you're missing authorization to call `ListUsers`, see the updated answer. If you're not familiar with Lambda, API Gateway and Identity Pools, doing it right would involve quite a bit of work. You might want to consider other paths.

Comment: I started to read the blog you mentioned. Not completely though. By the way: Is allowing access to the list of users the same as allowing access to a dynamoDB table? ..... I have the impression the way to go for me will be to use a Lambda function. My use case is that I want to enable 2 users to connect together if they wish.

Comment: It's the same principle, yes. It comes down to giving a user access to an API. Interaction with DynamoDB is done through API calls. It sounds to me like you have much reading to do on IAM permissions, API Gateway and Lambda functions. Might be a good idea to follow a course. Maybe look into AWS Amplify. Or find someone who can set those things up for you, if you'd rather focus on the mobile application side. That's a lot of moving parts to learn about. Or find a different, simpler way to do it. Like, if all you want is users exchanging emails, just have them message each other.

Comment: Well yes, but learning is not something I dislike. And I already got my hands on a number of things on AWS. One problem is that the word "simple" does not seem to exist in the AWS dictionary though. Beside if you have some tutorial to advice on AWS Amplify I'd be happy.

Comment: Of course the word "simple" exists, it's just that they only use it sarcastically. Seriously though, if you have time to learn, these are good skills to have. The official documentation is usually good and there are a lot of courses and tutorials out there. Can't recommend anything on Amplify because I don't use it. Their [blog posts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tag/amplify/) are usually a good start.


If you think that my response answered your question it might be useful to others to mark it as such.

Comment: The first time I heard about Amplify is in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uNtrLZhs5k
But it gave me a boost to do what I wanted to do.
So I assume there is a lot more to learn there and take advantage of.
The project I am working on now (for which the present post was made) actually started there too.